# Cómo tomar la longitud de una lista dinamicamente en React?

Tags: reactjs, arraylist

Estoy mostrando una lista de compañías que se pueden filtrar a través de algunos checkboxes. A continuación quiero mostrar por pantalla la cantidad de compañías que van apareciendo dinámicamente (ya sea que estén filtrados o no), pero únicamente consigo que se muestre la cantidad inicial de registros. Es decir, una vez que filtro registros no se modifica la cantidad de registros inicial que se muestra.

Este es mi código:

```
function App() {

  const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
  const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([
    { id: 1, status: "accepted", name: "001", date: "01/01/2022" },
    { id: 2, status: "accepted", name: "001", date: "01/01/2022" },
    { id: 8, status: "accepted", name: "001", date: "10/04/2022" },
    { id: 4, status: "declined", name: "005", date: "01/02/2022" },
    { id: 7, status: "pending", name: "005", date: "03/02/2022" },
    { id: 3, status: "pending", name: "001", date: "01/02/2022" },
    { id: 9, status: "pending", name: "002", date: "11/04/2022" },
    { id: 5, status: "declined", name: "002", date: "02/02/2022" },
    { id: 6, status: "declined", name: "001", date: "02/02/2022" },
]);

  const handleFilters = (data) => {
    let newFilters = {...filters};
    newFilters = data;  
    setFilters(newFilters);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">


      {/* Checkboxes filters */}
      <Checkbox 
        handleFilters={data => handleFilters(data)}
      />

      {/* companies list */}  
      <Title 
        title="Compañías"
      />
      <div>
        {companies.length ? 
          (
            <table>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>
                    ID 
                      <button onClick={() => sortBy('id')}>↑↓</button> 
                  </th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>
                    nombre
                    <button onClick={() => sortBy('name')}>↑↓</button> 
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Fecha
                    <button onClick={() => sortBy('date')}>↑↓</button> 
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                {/* Multicheckbox filters and data map */}
                {companies.filter((company) => 
                  filters.length > 0 ? filters.includes(company.status) : true
                )
                  .map((company, i) => (
                    <tr key={i}>
                      <td>{company.id}</td>
                      <td>{formatStatus(company.status)}</td>
                      <td>{company.name}</td>
                      <td>{company.date}</td>
                    </tr>
                  )
                )}
              </tbody>
            </table>   
          ) : (
            <h2>No hay compañías para mostrar</h2>
          )
        }
      </div>

      {/* list length */}

      <Title 
        title={'Cantidad de compañías: ' + companies.length}
      />
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

En el componente Title hago `companies.length` pero no me muestra el resultado correcto, sino que siempre muestra '9'

Comment: Claro, te muestra el largo fijo porque estas sacando el largo de companies, que es un arreglo que nunca cambia, ya que es la que contiene toda la data sin filtrar. Si necesitas mostrar el largo de la data filtrada, debes hacer algo muy similar al filter que implementaste en "Multicheckbox filters and data map".

Comment: Sip, era eso. Gracias!